# Matlab: Count values if signal changed for 0.1 in the last 2 seconds

Tags: matlab

I have a continuous signal rising and falling. I found peaks- maxima values and its locations.

I am wondering now how to write code to COUNT just in case my signal changed in this kind of rule: Its amplitude exceeded 0.1 and the peak occurred less than two seconds after the beginning of the increase.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have the signal as a static vector, or do you need to analyse something realtime? Please explain your data structure a bit more as well.

Comment: It's a static vector. So basically now I have signal in a vector and another vector with saved peak's locations and values. What I would need now is: Take first peak and see in the window of 2 seconds backwards if there was a value smaller than 1stPeakValue-0.1. If there was such a value i should count it, otherwise do nothing and go to the next peak and look the same

Comment: Hate to be nitpicky, but I don't think that you have a continuous signal. What you actually have is a _discrete_ signal, which is the result of another signal (which may or may not be continuous) sampled at different instances in time. Without knowing the time interval between two consecutive samples, what you're asking for is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

A general answer would be: loop through peak vector and check the appropriate part of the value vector for its smallest element:

```
for i = 1:len(peaks)
    peak = peaks(i,:)
    peak_value = peak[1]
    peak_time = peak[2]
    cut_values = values(max(1,(peak_time-2)*f):peak_time*f)
    if min(cut_values) < peak_value - 0.1
            peak_count += 1 % or something
```

edit - adding explanation:

`peaks` is the matrix (nx2) of peak values and times

`values` is your signal vector

`f` is the sampling frequency (Hz), considered uniform

Edited again to accomodate peaks before 2s.

Matlab's 1-indexing is a bit tricky here: sample 1 is at time 0, sample 2 at time `f`. So the really correct thing to do for a signal that starts at zero time is:

```
    cut_values = values(max(0,(peak_time-2)*f)+1:peak_time*f+1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It's more than clear. I am wondering now just how to correct it for the first peaks: If a peak is recognised at the beginning of my signal then I can't go back -0.1 because I get an error. But I want to analyse also those peaks, so maybe check and go back just for -0.01 or similar.

Comment: If you don't have the data for the last two seconds, what then can you do with a peak? PS: if it's a real-world signal and it's noisy, I wouldn't measure peaks like that.

Comment: I made a mistake before. I have OK data but for example if the first peak is detected at time=1.5 sec I would still need to go back and see changes. In the code I have now I get an error because I am going back 2 seconds in the signal which is just 1.5 seconds long. In the other words I would like to set the "going back interval" from for example 0.0001 to 2 seconds.

Comment: Assuming the call to values fails, try this: `values(max(0,(peak_time-2)*f):peak_time*f)`

Comment: Good thinking @Dennis Jaheruddin. I've edited the answer, the code should now work OK. I've just changed indexing to Matlab's 1-based.